# Python Strip ALL Spaces from DataFrame String Field

Tags: python, string, replace, strip, spaces

I have a Dataframe with the following column:

[image]

I am trying to remove all spaces (leading, trailing, and in-between). For example, 'Low Potential' should show as 'LowPotential'.  I have tried the following code but it did not appear to work:

```
df_merged_1['Priority Type'] = df_merged_1['Priority Type'].replace(' ', '')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` method; The *[Series.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)* method is meant to replace values literally (*exact match*), i.e, replace a value which is a whitespace in the series instead of stripping the white space from the string:

```
df_merged_1['Priority Type'] = df_merged_1['Priority Type'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

Alternatively, you can specify `regex=True` in the replace method:

```
df_merged_1['Priority Type'] = df_merged_1['Priority Type'].replace(' ', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: This gives SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: @JohnAndrews that's why in this cases it's best to follow his suggestion and insert "regex=True".